# How to select rows with a timestamp in a time period of a row that meets a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| TIMESTAMP | MACHNE_NO | ERR_CODE |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 9:00:00.0 |        17 |      100 |
| 9:00:00.1 |        15 |       58 |
| 9:00:00.1 |        17 |       68 |
| 9:00:01.5 |         9 |       18 |
| 9:00:01.6 |         9 |      100 |
| 9:00:01.9 |         9 |       95 |
| 9:00:02.7 |        15 |       18 |
| 9:00:02.8 |        17 |       18 |
| 9:00:03.2 |        17 |       22 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I have data like above and I would like to select the rows that contain errors for a machine three seconds after it has had ERR_CODE 100. So in the table I have shown, row 3 and 8 should be selected for machine 17 and row 5 for machine 9. Would anybody be able to show me a SQL query that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the problem and look for error code 100 in the 3 seconds before each error.  For this, use window functions and filtering.  For the *rows* with the errors:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             countif(err_code = 100) over (
                 partition by machine_no
                 order by unix_seconds(timestamp)
                 range between 3 preceding and current row
             ) as cnt_100
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_100 > 0 and err_code <> 100;
```

Note that any row with `err_code = 100` is going to meet the `countif()` condition.  However, those are filtered out by the outer `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks! One quick question, doesn't this return either all the events in the previous 3 seconds or the previous 3 events (which ever returns fewer)? If there are more than 3 errors in the last three seconds it will only return the first three

Comment: Probably `range between` instead of `rows between` was meant.

Answer (score 0):

`$machine no` is variable you are for what you want to get machine id

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `MACHNE_NO`='$machine_no' AND `ERR_CODE`='100' AND `TIMESTAMP`>=DATEADD(ss,-3,NOW()) AND `TIMESTAMP`<=NOW()"
```